# Text on a website beveled and coloring not working

Tags: html, css

I went on [my website](http://orikina.com) before I started working on it for the day and it has changed since last night.  All the text is messed up, the input text is now beveled and the NavBar text (un-hovered) is blue when it is set to `#999999` (grey).  Any idea how this happened or how to fix it?

Comment: I don’t see the beveling you’re talking about, but the navigation bar’s links are blue because of the rule at line 69 in styles.css.

Comment: Aliens took over your server and edited your code?   How are we supposed to know who messed it up since you last worked on it?  You fix it by inspecting the DOM and doing some routine troubleshooting.

Comment: @Sparky The point is the code was not tampered with, I was asking hoping for someone to tell me that GoogleChrome updated or like BenM did and tell me what I was doing wrong.

Comment: The point of my comment was to get you to realize that the most likely scenario is that you accidentally messed it up on your own.  Was anything learned by having somebody just point it out to you?  DOM inspection and troubleshooting is an invaluable skill for anyone writing front-end website code.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

The colour of visited links is set to `rgba(0,0,255,0.4)` on line 72 of `styles.css`...

```
media="all"
buttoncontainer, a:visited {
    color: rgba(0, 0, 255, .4);
}
```

Comment: I don't understand your answer, my CSS doc shows when you have in my editor.

Comment: I don't understand what you mean? Check your CSS file. The defintiion above definitely appears in your CSS file at line 72...

Comment: I see, thank you.  But how do I fix the input(search button and input text) ? and why did it show the navbar fine before I went to bed but was broken when I got up?

Comment: I don't know. You have the answer to your original question though.

Comment: Yes, I will mark it as the answer in 3min(when it lets me).